# images coming from api loading really slowly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, web, compression

I'm working on a Disney Plus clone web application and I'm encountering a problem with slow loading of images coming from an API. The application is built using JavaScript and ReactJS. I'm fetching the images from an API endpoint and displaying them on various pages.

The issue is that the images take a significant amount of time to load, resulting in a slow overall performance of the application. This affects the user experience and responsiveness.

here is the link to the website so you can test it : https://disneyplus-f1110.web.app/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Redis](https://redis.io/docs/getting-started/), which is an in-memory, key-value data store, to cache the images you want. It will significantly reduce the performance issues.

These are the [supported data types](https://redis.io/docs/data-types/).

Comment: To build up on this, You can also use lazy loading to only fetch/load images when user scrolls to it